# What's the fastest way to create and populate 50 arrays?

Tags: java, performance, multidimensional-array

I need to write a java code to create and populate 50 arrays (array1 to array50, with 10000000 rows and 3 columns each array):

create array**1**(1 To 10000000, 1 To 3) and populate it with file**1**.txt;

create array**2**(1 To 10000000, 1 To 3) and populate it with file**2**.txt;

[...]

create array**49**(1 To 1000000, 1 To 3) and populate it with file**49**.txt;

create array**50**(1 To 1000000, 1 To 3) and populate it with file**50**.txt;

What's the fastest way to accomplish this goal? Is it possible to use a loop so that it doesn't take so many lines of code?

Thanks.

Edit 1:
I'm sorry I was not clear previously.

In fact, I need to create 50 int arrays and fill each one with elements in the respective file.

Create int array**1** with 10000000 rows and 3 columns and populate it with elements in File**1**.txt;

Create int array**2** with 10000000 rows and 3 columns and populate it with elements in File**2**.txt;

I'm using this piece of code to create and populate each one of the 50 arrays:

```
int[][] array1 = new int [10000000][3];
List<List<String>> records = new ArrayList<>();
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(filepath/File1.txt"))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] values = line.split(",");
        records.add(Arrays.asList(values));
    }
}
```

As there are too many lines of code, I am trying to get a new code that could be faster and with less lines. I have already tryied to use an array of arrays. I wrote this piece of code, but it does not work (could someone please correct it?):

```
String arrayA[] = {"array1", "array2", "array3", "array4", "array5", "array6", "array7", "array8", "array9", "array10", "array11", "array12", "array13", "array14", "array15", "array16", "array17", "array18", "array19", "array20", "array21", "array22", "array23", "array24", "array25", "array26", "array27", "array28", "array29", "array30", "array31", "array32", "array33", "array34", "array35", "array36", "array37", "array38", "array39", "array40", "array41", "array42", "array43", "array44", "array45", "array46", "array47", "array48", "array49", "array50"};
for (int i = 0; i < arrayA.length; i++) {
    int[][] arrayA[i] = new int [10000000][3];
    List<List<String>> records = new ArrayList<>();
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader("C:/filepath/File" + i + 1 + ".txt"))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] values = line.split(",");
            records.add(Arrays.asList(values));
        }
    }
    System.out.println(arrayA[i][1][3]);
}
```

Comment: Yes, create an array of arrays and populate it in a loop.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by fastest and what this has to do with [tag:performance].

Comment: What does this mean: _create array1(1 To 10000000, 1 To 3) and populate it with "file1.txt"_? Does each array element contain the same string value `"file1.txt"`? So array1 contains 30 million elements, each with the string value `"file1.txt"`?

Comment: A fast way to create and populate 50 arrays is to find the fastest way to create and populate 1 array and do it 50 times in parallel threads.

Comment: @shmosel, I have already tryied to use an array of arrays. Could you please correct the code I wrote? See my edited message.

Comment: The **fastest** way can only be determined by benchmarking with your specific code, your files ... and your hardware.  Frankly, this whole question smells of *premature optimization*.

Comment: `arrayA` is a one-dimensional array.

Comment: @shmosel, what should be changed in order to make this array of arrays run properly?

Comment: If you really care about speed, replace your use of `split` with two `indexOf` calls.  Regular expressions may look short in your code, but there’s a lot of work being done under the hood.  In contrast, indexOf can be compiled by the JIT compiler to a single x86 instruction.

Comment: @VGR, I am searching stackoverflow, but so far I have found no example of a java code to fill a 2d int array using `indexOf`. Could you please help me adapt this piece of code to use `indexOf`?

Comment: @VGR actually, `split(",")` does not use the regex engine, as in case of the reference implementation, there is a short-cut for single character patterns. However, I don’t understand why the OP does this at all, when the goal seems to be to do something with that integer array which is not even touched in this loop…

Answer (score 1):

There may be a way to do it faster, but this is what I came up with:

```
public static String[][] generateArray(int rows, int cols, String value) {
    String[][] array = new String[rows][cols];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            array[i][j] = value;
        }
    }
    return array;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int numArrays = 50;
    final int rows = 1000000;
    final int cols = 3;

    List<String[][]> arrays = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>(numArrays));
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(numArrays);

    long start = System.nanoTime();
    for (int i = 0; i < numArrays; i++) {
        final String value = String.format("file%d.txt", i);
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                String[][] array = generateArray(rows, cols, value);
                try {
                    arrays.add(array);
                } finally {
                    latch.countDown();
                }
            }
        };
        executor.submit(runnable);
    }
    executor.shutdown();
    try {
        latch.await();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    long stop = System.nanoTime();
    long seconds = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toSeconds((stop - start));
    System.out.println("Completed in " + seconds + " seconds.");
}
```

Comment: I am sorry I was not clear previously. Could you please read the edited message? Thanks.